# Value in UserDefaults appears only after relaunch

Tags: ios, swift, codable, userdefaults

I'm storing Codable object and simple String in UserDefaults and after present a new screen where that value is used. For some reason Codable object is nil until I relaunch the app. String value is available right away.
To debug this issue I've tried to retrieve that object by tapping on a button but it always nil and doesn't matter when I'm trying to get this value. It only appears after restart

```
var user: Contact? = {
    if let contactData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: Constants.UserDefaultsKey.currentUser),
        let contact = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Contact.self, from: contactData) {
        return contact
    }
    return nil
}()

func storeUser(_ user: Contact) {
    do {
        let encodedUser = try JSONEncoder().encode(user)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedUser, forKey: Constants.UserDefaultsKey.currentUser)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: Constants.UserDefaultsKey.isLoggedIn)
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

struct Contact {
    var id: String?
    var email: String?
}

extension Contact: Codable {

enum ContactEncodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id
    case email = "email_address_work"
}

func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: ContactEncodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
    try container.encode(email, forKey: .email)
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: ContactEncodingKeys.self)
    id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
    email = try container.decode(String?.self, forKey: .email)
}
}
```

So `user` object is nil until relaunch

Comment: Where exactly in the code you posted are you having your issue? It's unclear.

Comment: I can see `ContactEncodingKeys` id does not have any string value. Key must be a string. It could be an issue. Did you notice it?

Comment: Your `var user` will be initialised as soon as this object is instantiated.  If this happens before the user defaults value is set then `user` will be `nil`.  It is not a computed variable so it doesn't get re-evaluated each time it is referenced.  Did you perhaps mean it to be a computed variable?  Also, there is no need to call `synchronize`

Comment: @Paulw11 you are right. Thanks

Comment: @ShamimHossain It's ok as long as "id" has same string value as key name

Comment: FYI - the call to `synchronize` is obsolete and unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently if you are accessing `user` property before setting the object in `UserDefaults`, it will just assign `nil` and will not compute again until you make a new object of this class. Change `user` property to computed as below.

```
var user: Contact? {
    if let contactData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: Constants.UserDefaultsKey.currentUser),
        let contact = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Contact.self, from: contactData) {
        return contact
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Other objects were computed except that one. Spend so much time on this stupid mistake

Comment: @NikolaiProkofev would you mind accepting the answer if it helped you fixing the issue. Thanks!